# How to count amount of students per university

Tags: php, sql, count, echo, distinct

I have a SQL database of university students, with the following details:

```
    Table_name: register
    Column_names: position, tertinst
```

The data in the database will look something like this:

```
    Coach..........UCT
    Athlete........Tukkies
    Official.......University of JHB
    Athlete........Tukkies
    Athlete........Tshwane Tech
    Manager........UCT
```

I need to count the amount of students who are athletes(position), per university(tertinst) and the output has to be something like this:

```
   UCT.....................735
   University of Jhb.......668
   Tukkies.................886
```

this is my attempt:

```
$positionx = 'Athletes';

include_once 'core/includes/db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT tertinst, COUNT(position) FROM register WHERE position = '$positionx' GROUP BY tertinst ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['COUNT(tertinst)'] . '......' . $row['COUNT(position)'];
}

$conn->close();
```

I get no result when the code is executed and I have searched for a different solution for hours, without success.

Comment: well, not your problem, but.... use mysqli functions instead of deprecated mysql functions. have a look on prepared statements for security and try to get usefull errors or warnings, have a look in your error.log

Comment: Typo? Replace `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` with `foreach($result as $row)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a few mistakes, and corrected the syntax in the sql count, as well as the echo. Here is the solution to my problem:

```
    <?php

include_once 'core/includes/db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT tertinst, COUNT(*) total FROM register WHERE position = 'Athletes' GROUP BY tertinst ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tertinst = $row["tertinst"];

    echo $tertinst . '......' . $row['total'] . '<br>';
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem? If it is a typo do you really think that people will find this question in the future and find this explanation useful. If the problem was only a typo you can delete the question instead.

Comment: Typo is just an expression for making mistakes. My answer is a combination of sql count solutions on the web that should help anyone who needs to do something similar. You can clearly see that the syntax with the sql count and the echo is different.

Comment: I correct the PHP opening tag. `<?php` should be instead of `<?` If you have the wrong one in your code, please fix that also

Comment: Thanks! I will do.